# Custom Dynamic Flask WTForm

Tags: sqlite, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I am trying to build a WTForm to add elements into a SQLite Table. The table has only two cols (id and name)

routes.py:

```
@app.route('/systems', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def systems():

    form = SystemForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        system = Systems(name=form.systemname.data)
        db.session.add(system)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('systems'))
    return render_template('systems.html', title='Systems', form=form)
```

forms.py:

```
class SystemForm(FlaskForm):

    systemname = StringField('System', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Add')
```

But before the form I want to display all the rows already present in table:

- system 1
- system 2
  ....

  textfield / submit button

How can I accomplish this supposed I can grab the rows by the following:

```
database = "mydb.db"
conn = create_connection(database)
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM systems")
data = cur.fetchall()
```

Will have the list to be part of the form definition? Or can be put before the form tag like the following (being data the returned rows from the sqlite query):

```
    {% for item in data %}
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>{{item[1]}}</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    {% endfor %}
```

How can i pass data to the html template?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have already done everything, the only thing to do is;

```
@app.route('/systems', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def systems():
    form = SystemForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        system = Systems(name=form.systemname.data)
        db.session.add(system)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('systems'))
    # perform your database lookup to get `data`
    return render_template('systems.html', title='Systems', form=form, data=data)
```

Comment: Thanks I also implemented the above with a delete function also

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route('/systems', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def systems():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form.get('submit') == 'Add':
            form = SystemForm()
            if form.validate_on_submit():
                system = Systems(name=form.systemname.data)
                db.session.add(system)
                db.session.commit()
                return redirect(url_for('systems'))
        else:
            delete_ids = request.form.getlist('delete_id')
            for delete_id in delete_ids:
                db.session.query(Systems).filter(Systems.id==delete_id).delete()
            db.session.commit()

    data = db.session.query(Systems)
    form = SystemForm()
    return render_template('systems.html', title='Systems', form=form, data=data)
```